# Linear ordering of vertices of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider a linear ordering $\pi$ of vertices in $V$ and an independent set $I$ of any graph $G(V,E)$ depending on $\pi$ as follows. Define $I =\big\{v \in V ~|~u \in N(v) \text{ does not precede } v \in \pi \big\}$. Show that there exists a linear ordering such that $|I| \geqslant \displaystyle \sum_{v \in V } \frac{1}{d(v)+1}$. Here, $d(v)$ denotes the degree of vertex $v$.

---

Any kind of help is utmost welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The relation $v\in\pi$ does not make sense, since you said $v$ is a vertex and $\pi$ is a linear ordering of the vertices. What does it mean for a vertex to be an element of a linear ordering of vertices? Perhaps you meant to write that $u$ does not precede $v$ in $\pi$??

Comment: The definition of $I$ seems to depend on the choice of a vertex $u$ in $N(v)$. Unless you left out a quantifier and meant to say that **some** vertex $u$ in $N(v)$ does not precede $v$ in the ordering $\pi$??

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the `depending on $\pi$' bit, this becomes the well known *Caro-Wei Theorem*. There is a standard probabilistic argument that proves this, but it can be done recursively too (and the recursive proof is also a known thing, and gives you a nice linear ordering on the vertices that does what you want). We will describe a process for generating an ordering $\pi$.

---

For a hint: Consider a vertex of minimum degree, and it's neighborhood. See what happens if you put this vertex first in the order, its neighbours right after, remove all these from the graph, and repeat. Full proof is below.

---

> Let $G_0 = G = (V,E)$ be our graph. Among the vertices of $G$, let $v_1$ be a vertex of minimum degree. Begin creating our ordering $\pi$ by letting $v_1$ be the first vertex in the linear order (which we'll denote by $\pi(1) = v_1$, and letting the neighbors of $v_1$ have position $2$ up to $d(v_1)+1$. So if $u\in N(v_1)$, then $2\leq \pi(u) \leq d(v_1) + 1$.

> Now set $G_1 = G_0 - N[v_1]$ (i.e., $G_1$ is the graph we get by removing $v_1$ and its neighbors from $G_0$). Let $v_2$ be a vertex of minimum degree in $G_1$. Put $v_2$ next in the linear order, so $\pi(v_2) = d(v_1) + 2$. Put all the vertices of $N(v_2)\cap V(G_1)$ directly after $v_2$ in the linear order. We'll denote $N_i^* = N(v_i)\cap V(G_{i-1})$ for convenience.

> Repeat this process of picking a vertex $v_{k+1}$ of minimum degree in $G_k$, letting $G_{k+1} = G_k - N[v_{k+1}]$, and placing $v_{k+1}$ and all its remaining neighbors of $N_{k+1}^*$ next in the linear order. By the graph's finiteness, this process will end and we'll get a linear ordering $\pi$ on the vertices.

> The set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_i\}$ is our candidate for $I$. It certainly satisfies your independence condition (and is, in fact, independent in the usual sense!). To prove the size condition, notice that for all neighbors $u\in N(v_1)$, $d(u) + 1 \geq d(v_1) + 1 = |N[v_1]|$. So $$\sum_{u\in N[v_1]} \frac{1}{d(u) + 1} \leq |N[v_1]|\cdot\frac{1}{1+d(v_1)} \leq 1$$ We also get a similar inequality for each of the next removed neighborhoods $N_k^*$: $$\sum_{u\in N_k^*} \frac{1}{d(u) + 1} \leq |N_k^*|\cdot \frac{1}{1 + d(v_k)} \leq 1$$ Since each vertex appears in exactly one set of the form $N_k^*$, we can put this all together as: $$\sum_{u\in V}\frac{1}{1 + d(u)} = \sum_{k = 1}^{|I|}\left( \sum_{u\in N_k^*} \frac{1}{d(u) + 1} \right) \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{|I|} 1 = |I|$$